# C++: implementing a global constant whose value is given by the user

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants, header-files, extern

First of all, let me say I have read similar threads on how to initialize a global variable or how to properly implement global constants. Nevertheless, these questions did not really help me with my concrete problem, as also haven't any other ressources I've consulted. The problem is the following.

I (have to) declare in a header file header.h a variable that must be constant and used by the main function in main.cpp as well as other functions defined in a another file functions.cpp (that are previously declared in header.h). The problem is this constant is a runtime constant, whose value is given by the user. How should I proceed?

I think my best shot was to do as follows. In header.h

```
// Header guard

namespace n
{
    // Some forward declarations

    extern const double mu; // The constant that should be initialized by the user.

    // Some other declarations
}
```

then in functions.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

namespace n
{
    // Some definitions here

    double function_that_uses_mu(double a, double b)
    {
        // Some code using mu

        return somedouble;
    }

    // Some other definitions
}
```

finally main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Some code

    double value_of_mu{};
    std::cin >> value_of_mu;        
    // Validity check
    extern const double n::mu{ value_of_mu };

    // More code

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that compilation fails due to the fact that `error: ‘mu’ has both ‘extern’ and initializer`. However, if I tried `mu = value_of_mu` I would obviously get an error because I would be assigning to a const value (not initialising it). So I don't know how to proceed, or what's wrong with my code. There are two mandatory facts I must respect:

1. Functions/global-consts definitions, functions/global-consts declarations and main must be split in the three aforementioned files.
2. mu is to be defined as a constant shared by all three files.

Is this possible? How?

EDIT:

I think my problem is that an exten variable can't be initialised inside a function, but if this is so, I don't see how I do what I'm trying to.

Comment: Just drop the `extern` when you initialize `mu`, not the type specifiers. That should fix it, I *think*.

Comment: `error: ‘const double mu’ conflicts with a previous declaration`

Comment: It's in a different namespace, so initialize `n::mu`.

Comment: @cigien Actually that was a mistake I made copying it here. On my code the scope was correctly resolved.

Comment: Ok, see my answer below.

Comment: In the end it's not really a constant, and you shouldn't try to pretend it's a constant by declaring it as `const`.   If you don't want the program to accidentally change its value, you have to protect it in some other way, such as making it a private member variable of a class.

Comment: That's something I thought, @Spencer. Probably I should implement it as a private static member (so it is shared), with only a const accessor function, and intialize it through the constructor. Actually it makes a ton of sense given that the functions using `mu` are actually methods. Nevertheless I wondered if I was doing something wrong (semantically or syntactically) or just asking for something impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it: If a value needs to be set during the lifetime of a program, it's not really a constant.  So, you shouldn't try to pretend it's a constant by declaring it as `const`.   If you don't want the program to accidentally change its value, you have to protect it in some other way, such as making it a private member variable of a class.  That way, you can restrict access to only return the value of `mu` as a const.

```
// muholder.h

class muholder
{
 private:
    double m_value;
 public:
    muholder (double ivalue): m_value(ivalue) {}
    double const &value() const { return m_value; }
};

// workflow_envelope.h

class workflow_envelope
{
    private:
    muholder m_mu;

    public:
    workflow_envelope (double imu): m_mu(imu) {}
    bool validity_check();
    double method_that_uses_mu (double a, double b) const  { return a*m_mu.value()/ b; }
    void run(); // any "more code" goes in here. 
};

// main
#include "workflow_envelope.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Some code

    double value_of_mu;
    if (std::cin >> value_of_mu)
    {      
      // Validity check
      workflow_envelope workflow(value_of_mu);
      if (workflow.validity_check())
      {
         workflow.run();  
         return 0;
      }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: My main problem was to think that a physical, contigent constant should be implemented as a global, runtime contant. The envelope is a good idea!

Comment: @toritoverdejo I use the same main for most programs, and it only contains wrapper code. All of the workflow-specific stuff goes in the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a variable, you can't specify `extern`. This should work instead:

```
int main()
{
    // Some code

    double value_of_mu{};
    std::cin >> value_of_mu;        
    // Validity check
    using namespace n;
    const double mu = value_of_mu;  // no extern specifier

    // More code

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `error: qualified-id in declaration before ‘{’ token`

Comment: Ok, I think `{}` are not allowed in this context. Updated the answer.

Comment: It changes nothing, still creates a conflict of multiple declarations. On the other hand, it makes little sense that uniform initialization of a fundamental data type was not allowed while copy initialization was.

Comment: Ok, it seems the qualifier id is an issue, though I'm not sure why. The edited answer works on my machine. Also not sure why `{}` doesn't work here.

Comment: does it work including a header file with a namespace where `extern const double mu;` is declared?

Comment: Yes, though I didn't try a second `.cpp` file that uses `mu`.

Comment: By the way, you can use `extern` to initialize a const variable that somewhere else has been declared as `extern const` (and actually I think you must), but you must do it in the global namespace.